# Search by element of an object in a array

Tags: mongodb

Say I have the following object:

```
{
    players: [{_id: "someid"}]
}
```

How can I query this collection for all objects that have an object in `players` that has the `_id` of `someid`?

Comment: `collection.select { |_, v| v[_id] == "someid" }`

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: apparently this is a mongodb question, not ruby question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, heck, so in mongo _find_ does Ruby's _select_?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: mongo's "find" is like SQL's "select where"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({'players._id': 'someid'})
```

It's called [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

Comment: Sergio, _all_ objects, not just one.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: it's not ruby :)

Comment: @ChristianStewart: yep.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, ic =)))