# How to display only the mongodb documents in which the viewer id is found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using node js, mongodb and mongoose.
I have stored surveys in the data base.

> Survey Schema

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var SurveySchema = new Schema({ 
    surveyname: String,
    _id : String,
    createrName : String,
    takers : [{
        takerName : String
    }],
    question : [{
        que: String,
        ans1: String,
        ans2: String,
        ans3: String,
        ans4: String,
        ans5: String

        }]
    });

 module.exports=mongoose.model('Survey',SurveySchema);
```

I have stored the takers who can view the survey in an array. When a user views the inbox, I want to display only the surveys in which a particular takerName is found.

say currentUser is 'James'. I want to display all the surveys in which 'James' is found in takerName and not display the surveys if the name 'James' is not found in takerName

How can I do this in mongoose? What option of mongoose I can use for this?

Comment: that means when you query you want to hide certain fields

Comment: not hide fields.. say currentUser is 'James'. I want to display all the surveys in which 'James' is found in takerName and not display the surveys if the name 'James' is not found in takerName

Comment: `var query = Survey.find({ 'takerName': 'James' });   query.exec(function (err, results) {   if (err) return handleError(err);  // do something with results })`

Comment: I tried this. takerName is inside the takers array and I think this is not accessing takerName.

Comment: I found it!!  var mcqSurvey = Survey.find({ takers: { $elemMatch: { takerName: "James" } } });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search by element of an object in a array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343650/search-by-element-of-an-object-in-a-array)