# How to get specific values of an embedded document Array in MongoDB using Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

what I tried to is getting all sitename from every embedded documents in the array.I have tried using following syntax but didn't work

(  sites.$.site )

```
{
  "user" : "username",
  "sites" : [{
      "sitename" : "site.com",
      "url" : "site.com",
      }, {
      "sitename" : "site2.com",
      "url" : "site2.com",
      },{
      "sitename" : "site2.com",
      "url" : "site2.com",
   }]
}
```

Comment: "sites.$.site" seems to be a typo. Surely "sites.sitename" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search by element of an object in a array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343650/search-by-element-of-an-object-in-a-array)

Comment: I want to list all sitenames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding distinct from collections in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246302/finding-distinct-from-collections-in-mongodb). Use "sites.sitename" as name key in linked answer for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo-java,

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Test");

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection");
        ArrayList<Document> doc = new ArrayList<Document>();
        doc.add(new Document().append("$unwind","$sites"));
        doc.add(new Document().append("$project",new Document().append("sitename","$sites.sitename")));
        List<Document> results =collection.aggregate(doc).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
        for(Document res: results){
            System.out.println(res.toJson());
        }
```

output:

```
        { "_id" : { "$oid" : "58c26ce044400b08ca6ff483" }, "sitename" : "site.com" }
        { "_id" : { "$oid" : "58c26ce044400b08ca6ff483" }, "sitename" : "site2.com" }
        { "_id" : { "$oid" : "58c26ce044400b08ca6ff483" }, "sitename" : "site2.com" }
```

Comment: why do u use Document Instead of BasicDbObject ? i used BasicDbObject  and did some changes. but it works thanks

Comment: from mongodb3.0 onwards MongoCollection insert ,update, qurery ,aggregate and most of methods accept only org.bson.Document